# boot2docker on windows - Unable to pull images

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am trying to explore dockers. I have got boot2docker installed on my windows machine. My machine is behind corporate firewall.

When I execute the simple command like the one below, I get the error that prevents images being pulled. Any help here ?
Even when I changes the dns nameserver ( in /etc/resolv.conf) to 8.8.8.8 , I have the same issue.

I looked at other issues posted on same subject . Did not get any help .
Please help

**Error**

> docker@boot2docker:~$ docker run -it --rm tomcat:8.0 Unable to find
>   image 'tomcat:8.0' locally

Pulling repository tomcat
**Get [link](https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/tomcat/images): dial tcp: loo
kup index.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout**

Comment: Can you ping the machine with `ping 10.0.2.3` from your Boot2Docker VM?

Comment: Yes , I am able to ping the 10.0.2.3 from Boot2Docker VM.

Answer (score 0):

When your host is on the VPN, your `boot2docker-vm` VM may not have access to the internet at all; in particular if your connection is bridged. You can try `NAT`.

- https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/628

Comment: I am still not get the docker running.